Function where words don't be replaced using Regex
I have a script where i annonymize personal data, so when a string have some words that start with capital letters it replace them by another function ( that is to annonymize names)
I want to write a function where the regex is looking for words that is given in a list.
When a string has one of the words in the given list  it should not replaced. To give an example:
Mijn naam is kim en ik heb een opleiding gevolgd aan de Universiteit van Amsterdam
So because Universiteit van Amsterdam is been write with capital letters is will be annonymized by annother function. I want to make an extra function that use Regex where an given list with certain words will be ignored when when a string matches the words in the list.
I have a function that replace it, but i want that the matches words are ignored.
This is the function that anonymizeNames**
def anonymizeNames(sentence):
    '''
        :param sentence: the input sentence
        :return: the sentence without names
    '''

    ##define x
    x = ""

    ##Check naam: indication
    names0Reg = "[Aa]chternaam:|[Vv]oornaam:|[Nn]aam:|[Nn]amen:"
    res = re.search(names0Reg, sentence)
    if res != None:
        ##Achternaam:, voornaam: or naam: or namen: occurs; next Standardize
        sentence = re.sub('[Nn]amen:', 'naam:', sentence)
        sentence = re.sub('[Aa]chternaam:', 'naam:', sentence)
        sentence = re.sub('[Vv]oornaam:', 'naam:', sentence)
        sentence = re.sub('Naam:', 'naam:', sentence)

        ##Extract names
        names00Reg = "naam: [A-Za-z]+"
        x = re.findall(names00Reg, sentence)
        for y in x:
            ##remove naam:\s
            y = re.sub('naam: ', '', y)
            ##Check for tussenvoegsels
            if y in tussenVList:
                ##Add next word
                regTest = y + " " + "[A-Za-z]+"
                x2 = re.search(regTest, sentence)
                if x2 != None:
                    ##Name found
                    y = x2.group()
                    ##replace
                   sentence = re.sub(y, strz, sentence)

    ##Always check sentences for names 1
    names1Reg = "[Ii]k [Bb]en ([A-Z]{1}[a-z ]{2,})+[\\.\\,]*"
    res = re.search(names1Reg, sentence)
    if res != None:
        ##adjust result
        x = re.sub('[Ii]k [Bb]en ', '', res.group())
        x = re.sub('[\\,\\.]', '', x)
        ##use NLP to only keep names
        

    ##Always check sentences for names 2
    names2Reg = "[Mm]ijn [Nn]aam is ([A-Z]{1}[a-z\s-]{2,})+[\\.\\,]*"
    res = re.search(names2Reg, sentence)
    if res != None:
        ##adjust result
        x = re.sub('[Mm]ijn [Nn]aam is ', '', res.group())
        x = re.sub('[\\,\\.]', '', x)
        ##use NLP to only keep names
        

    ##Check for single letter followed by dot and series of letters
    if x == "":
        regNameLet = "^[A-Z]{1}\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}|\s[A-Z]{1}\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        res = re.search(regNameLet, sentence)
        if res != None:
            ##replace word in sentence, first at start
            sentence = re.sub('^[A-Z]{1}\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}', strz, sentence)
            ##next in sentence with additional space
            strY = " " + strz
            sentence = re.sub('\s[A-Z]{1}\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}', strz, sentence)

    ##Check for occurence of two subsequent uppercase words (might be a name)
    if x == "":
        res = re.findall("[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,}\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,}", sentence)
        if res != []:
            for y in res:
                if len(y) > 1:
                    ##replace name with strX
                    sentence = re.sub(y, strz, sentence)

    ##Always recheck remaining sentence with NLP to make sure all personal info is removed
    sentence = pureNLP2(sentence)  ##pureNLP2 tries to include entity checks

    return (sentence)

This is my function for finding names of university and with this function i don't want to replace them
school ['Hogenschool Amsterdam', 'Universiteit van Amsterdam']
strX='xxx'

def school (sentence):
   for schoolname in school:
     res = re.findall(schoolname,sentence)
     if res !=[]:
        for y in res:
            if len(y) >1:
               sentence = replaceNice(sentence, strX, y)
      return(sentence)
print(school('Mijn naam is Kim en ik volg een opleiding aan de Universiteit van Amsterdam'))

output : Mijn naam xxx en ik volg een opleiding aan de xxx xxx
The output that i want is:
Mijn naam is Kim en ik volg een opleiding aan de Universiteit van Amsterdam
I think i have a start. But when i want to finish the variable sentence im a bit stuck, because here i want to say if the string has matching words from the list School don't replace it, but just print it back.

I think you don't have to use a regex here right? You have a list of strings that you want to replace with something if they exist in the sentence correct?

Ya I agree with @Thefourthbird but I am not sure if you want to replace it or do something else?

I don't want to replace them, they get replaced by another function with is for  finding names, and because people describe the names of the university with capital letters the another function think he its a a name. Do you any other idea ? @Thefourthbird

No i don't want to replace them, it just i you find a matching word in the sentence don't replace it if you think i can do it different please let me know @Flow

Your post has contradictions. You write: "because Universiteit van Amsterdam is been write with capital letters is will be annonymized by annother function", but also "if the string has matching words from the list School don't replace it, but just print it back.". So you want to replace or not?

@trincot no I don’t want to replace it,

Then what do you mean with "is will be annonymized by annother function"?

Can you please provide runnable code, that takes example input and outputs the result, and explain what is wrong with the result? There are too many vague statements and code here.

The goal of my whole script is to replace personal data. So that function recognize words in the middle of the sentence where Capital letters are been used. So when people describe a university they use capital letters  and that can be pattern of a name and last name and it will be replaced, but the university should not be replaced

As I understand Leyla's request, the initial idea is to replace all names with anonymized names to protect identity. Leyla's idea was to replace all capitalized words. However, this runs into the issue of replacing other proper nouns like Universiteit van Amsterdam.

@MichaelCao yes indeed do you have an idea how i can solve this

Can you extend the function that makes the data anonymous have an extra check for the  school list? Or add that function to the question to make it more clear to the readers.

The function you provided is not runnable. Can you make it runnable? Please resolve dependencies and indentation errors.

@MichaelCao this what i wanted but i add one smal quetiosn to the comments

Use a function in re.sub() to calculate the replacement dynamically. It can check if the word is in the list and leave it unchanged.

Replace all the safe words with a lower case version, then anonymize, then restore the lower cased safe words to their original form.
test_strings = ['Adam goes to Universiteit van Amsterdam', 'George goes to Washington College', 'Anthony Hopkins is a student at Johns Hopkins']
safe_words = ['Universiteit van Amsterdam', 'Johns Hopkins', 'Washington College']

def anonymize(sentence, safe_words):
    restore = {}

    for word in safe_words:
        sentence = sentence.replace(word, word.lower())

        restore[word.lower()] = word
    
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word[0].isupper():
            sentence = sentence.replace(word, word[0]+'.')
    
    for word, restored_word in restore.items():
        sentence = sentence.replace(word, restored_word)
    
    return sentence

for sentence in test_strings:
    print(anonymize(sentence, safe_words))

Output:
A. goes to Universiteit van Amsterdam
G. goes to Washington College
A. H. is a student at Johns Hopkins


This a great function, but i want to apply it on an column in a dataframe, i have to write it like this:  df['persoonlijke informatie'].apply(anonymize, safe_words) @michealCao

df.apply allows you to pass keyword arguments. Just use df['persoonlijke informatie'].apply(anonymize, safe_words = safe_words).
